# Page is Redirecting to http://www.localhost.com in my asp.net application

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, localhost

I am facing a big issue with Visual Studio when I am running my asp.net application. It's redirecting me to `http://www.localhost.com` and I am not able to debug as well as run the application. Earlier I got this issue and I had to format my system. Now I don't want to format my system can anybody suggest to me how I can solve this issue?

My current "hosts" file settings:

```
# #localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
#   #127.0.0.1       http://localhost
#   #::1             localhost
```

Comment: What browser is this? Are you using Google Chrome?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/657383/localhost-lookup-fails-browser-tries-www-localhost-com-instead

Answer (score 0):

```
# #localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
   127.0.0.1       http://localhost
   #::1             localhost
```

you should remove #, # means its a comment

Comment: I followed the same steps but still getting same issue.

Comment: Stange... do you have enything in your IIS?